# What's the difference between contain and include in English?

Tags: grammar, differences, synonyms, word-usage, comparisons

What's the difference between:
'his question didn't include a link on Yahoo answers? ' and 
'his question didn't contain a link on Yahoo answers? '
(I want to say there wasn't a link in his question on Yahoo answers).

Someone mentioned there are subtle differences, but just can't tell what they are, so I am wondering that you guys here might have the answer. please help me out. 
thanks folks!

By the way, I am a freshman here. any opinion that regarding the DIFFERENCE between them are appreciated,  please feel free to express your opinion, thank you very much your answers!

Comment: ***contain*** just talks about presence. ***inclusion*** gets at *intent*

Comment: The rental of a car from XYZ Co includes the use of a downtown garage slot.  But I doubt that you can make the car contain the slot.

Comment: it's a helpful real life example to better understand the difference, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's indeed a subtle but important difference between these two terms in the context of the scenario you describe.

**Include** expresses a greater degree of ownership over the object in question (the link) and seems to suggest the user actively worked to incorporate it in their answer. This connotation arises from the fact that *including* is something a user does, but the answer is what *contains* (something). In other words, the two terms emphasize two different aspects (the user or the answer) of the same scenario. **Contain** merely refers to the link appearing somewhere in the answer.

In all honesty, though, one term isn't more appropriate than the other. You could say:

> Your answer should contain a link.

Or you could also say:

> You should include a link in your answer.

But it doesn't matter which you choose.

Comment: thank you very much for your helpful answer!  so you mean contain merely talking about the presence of the object(the link), whereas include suggest intention involved with the link?

Comment: @user239460 Precisely.

Comment: alright, i think i am close to discern the difference between them.

Comment: Also worth noting is that you could say an answer contains OR includes a link (in the latter case, it's sort of like personifying the answer), but you CAN'T say a user contains a link. in that sense, contain strictly refers to what the answer has in itself, while include is a bit more flexible.

Comment: thanks for you reminding. right now i shape up my understanding as: contain means what's originally within; include means the extra has been added to as a part of the whole thing, it emphasizes on the part rather the whole. contain is natural whereas include is intended.

Comment: Yep, pretty much, except that include is not always natural--an answer may contain something because it was *included*. Basically, "contain" is about something being present, whether naturally or by inclusion. Include emphasizes the intent and the action of incorporating something to be part of the whole.

Comment: oh, i see, but you said include is not aways natural?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; you may have misinterpreted what I wrote. Feel free to let me know which part confused you and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: you said "except that include is not always natural", i thought you said that CONTAIN is not aways natural. and that's my understanding of contain.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. You're right--I meant to say that "contain is not always natural".

Answer (score 1):

Purely in the context of the question, there ins no relevant difference between *contain* and *include*.

Normally, though, the difference is by no means subtle

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=to+contain&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=to+contain&aqs=chrome..69i57.2903j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=to+contain+definition 
speaks of having or holding while https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=to+include&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=to+include&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61.2735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=to+include+definition speaks of comprising or making part of a whole.

How are those the same, please?

Comment: i am sorry but Google isn't available in my country. but the subtle difference is what i am trying to figure out.

Comment: Really? Well, that first link basically said to *contain* is to have or hold (someone or something) within, or to control or restrain (oneself or a feeling).

The other said *include* is to comprise or contain as part of a whole, or to make part of a whole or set…

The differences are in no way relevant in the context of whether there was a link in a question…